# A few extra pixels of height - where could they be coming from?

Tags: html, css

On, e.g., this link: http://4ad.com/releases/20949, if you look at the album cover image in the top right part of the page, the black border is not quite square: there are a few extra pixels of height at the bottom.

As far as I can tell the image is 300x300 pixels in size.  There are no obvious (to us!) sources of the extra 4.5 pixels of height.  Does anyone know what could be creating such a discrepancy?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since the image is `inline`, it's treated as text, which means a few extra pixels are added to the bottom as leading. Displaying the image as a block (i.e. adding `display: block;`) solves the problem nicely.

Comment: Yes it does!  Thank you for an effective solution which also explains the nature of the problem - exactly what I needed!

Comment: Alternatively, use `vertical-align: top` or `middle` or `bottom` on the img. See http://jsfiddle.net/Gu6pG/1/ for the difference.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Why isn't that an answer? Helped me! :D

Answer (score 5):

By default, images are displayed as `inline-block` and aligned with the `baseline` of the text.
 The extra space is added for [Descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender).

To fix it, use `vertical-align: top` or `middle` or `bottom` on the img. See http://jsfiddle.net/Gu6pG/3 for the difference.

Comment: +1 - Helped me out when I was trying to figure out where some mysterious extra pixels were comming from. Using vertical align on the image element fixed it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Change image to be displayed as **block element** by adding this setting to your **style.css** file:

```
/* consolidate this CSS style */
#rightbox_packshot img {
    width: 300px; /* from line 2896 in style.css */
    height: 300px; /* from line 1498 in style.css */
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `float:left` (or right) in place of `display:block` which does make the image a `block` element but allows you to keep additional text (if you have it) inline.